# Clojure uberjar on Java 1.5

Tags: java, deployment, clojure

I created an uberjar with `lein uberjar` and I'm able to run it on my machine (java 1.8 is installed) via:

```
java -jar my.jar
```

On the server I want to deploy it, I'm getting an error. There, however only java version 1.5 is installed. Here is the error message and the complete version description:

```
java -jar my.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce
[...]



java -version
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: what version of clojure do you use?

Comment: Why would you assume that software using java 1.8 features would run on a medieval VM? Which is not even a "real" java?

Comment: @GyroGearless, Anton is using Clojure 1.8, not Java 1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Java 1.6. Starting from version 1.6 Clojure [drops support for Java 1.5](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#11-jdk-version-update).